# How to use UNNotificationPresentationOptions

Tags: ios, swift, usernotifications

In iOS 10 , there is an option for presenting the notification when the app is in foreground using **UNNotificationPresentationOptions**,

but i couldn't find any sample on how to use this, please suggest some idea about how to implement this feature

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have implemented the foreground notification by

Adding the below code in my viewController

```
extension UIViewController: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    public func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Swift.Void) {
        completionHandler( [.alert, .badge, .sound])
    }

    public func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Swift.Void) {
        print("Do what ever you want")

    }

}
```

In my Appdelegate on didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert,.sound]) {(accepted, error) in

            if !accepted {   
                print("Notification access denied")
            }            
        }
```

Comment: Don't forget to call `completionHandler()` at the end of `userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:withCompletionHandler:)`. If you don't call it, you'll probably get unwanted behavior. See [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate/1649501-usernotificationcenter) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

The new iOS 10 [UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate) now has a single set of methods for handling both remote and local notifications.

`UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` protocol:

`userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:withCompletionHandler:)`

Called to let your app know which action was selected by the user for a given notification.

`userNotificationCenter(_:willPresent:withCompletionHandler:)`

Delivers a notification to an app running in the foreground.

Two methods. And what’s better, is that now that they are moved into their own protocol, the iOS 10

`UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` so this will help clean up your existing `UIApplicationDelegat`e by being able to refactor all that old notification handling code into a shiny, new, cohesive protocol of it’s own.

Here’s an example:

```
extension NotificationManager: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: () -> Void) {

    switch response.actionIdentifier {

    // NotificationActions is a custom String enum I've defined
    case NotificationActions.HighFive.rawValue:
        print("High Five Delivered!")
    default: break
    }
}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

    // Delivers a notification to an app running in the foreground.
}
}
```